# How to bulid a criteria query to get the data of my domain

Tags: grails, criteria, hibernate-criteria

I know that have to be really easy, but I'm new in grails and I don't find any clear answer. That I want to do is read and get with a criteria query the data that I have in my domain do a search for each parameter.

This is my domain Person:

```
    String name
    String surname
    String address
    String village
    String country
```

This is that I'm trying to do:

```
def getData = Person.createCriteria()
```

I can see in the log that I have an object (com.mypackagename.Person: 1.), but not the data that I have in the database. example (myname, mysurname, myaddress, myvillage, mycountry)

I only have one row of data in my database and I want to get the data of every column and do a search for each parameter

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me show you the code first, then I'll explain it:

```
class SomeController {

    def search() {
        def people = Person.withCriteria {
            params
                .findAll { name, value -> name in ['name', 'surname', 'address', 'village', 'country'] }
                .each { name, value -> eq(name, value) }
        }

        // Do as you please with 'people'; a list of Person instances.
    }
}
```

Ok, so let's say you have a controller method (ex. `search()`) which receives the query parameters from the user. The parameters would be in the `params` Map. For example, if the user searches for the name *John* and the country *USA*, `params` would look like this: `[name: 'John', country: 'USA']`. Even though there are other search parameters available, we won't use them because the user did not specify them.

Within the criteria query, first search for the `param` key/value pairs which you care about; the searchable properties of `Person`. Then, for each of those pairs call `eq(String propertyName, Object value)` to set up the query criteria (the WHERE clause).

Using the example data, Hibernate will generate SQL that looks something like this:

```
SELECT name, surname, address, village, country 
FROM person 
WHERE name = 'john' AND country = 'USA'
```

And that's it!

Note: You will see the same output in the log (ex. com.mypackagename.Person: 1). That's because you're logging `personInstance.toString()`. So if you want the log entry to look differently, you'll need to override `Person.toString()` A *very* easy way to remedy this is to use Groovy's [@ToString](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/next/html/gapi/groovy/transform/ToString.html) AST.

For more about creating criteria queries, take a look at my series of [articles](http://emmanuelrosa.com/articles/gorm-for-sqladdicts-where-clause/). I cover criteria queries using SQL terminology.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
def persons = Person.createCriteria().list{}
```

or if you want just one result:

```
def persons = Person.createCriteria().list { 
    maxResults 1 
}
```

Moreover please read about [using Criteria](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.0.x/guide/GORM.html#criteria) and  [Querying with GORM](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.0.x/guide/GORM.html#querying)

Comment: I need to do a search for each parameter that I have in the domain, and have to be with criteria, is a requirement

Comment: I get a "Could not find which method list() to invoke from this list:" if i add .list()

Comment: I get in the log com.mypackagename.Person: 1. That I want is get the data, eg: Jhon, McCan, C/.....,

Comment: so just get from result list what you want: `persons.each{ print it.name }`